# The first subfigure appears rotated and very large

Tags: graphics, subfloats

The used the following script in LaTeX but the first subfigure is very large and rotated. I am using `subcaption` package. The figure is 1920x1080. I used this code twice in the script; the first is working fine but the second is not. It does not work with `\linewidth`.

```
\begin{figure} [!h]
            \centering
            \begin{subfigure}[!h]{0.9\textwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    \includegraphics[scale=0.20, keepaspectratio]{fig1.png}
                \end{center}
                \caption{cap1}
                \label{fig1}
            \end{subfigure}

            \begin{subfigure}[!h]{0.9\textwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{fig2.png}
                \end{center}
                \caption{cap2}
                \label{fig2}
            \end{subfigure}
            \caption{cap}
            \label{fig}
        \end{figure}
```

Comment: What does »filliped« mean?

Comment: Try `width=0.8\linewidth` instead of `width=0.8\textwidth`.

Comment: `!h` is not a valid (optional) argument of `subfigure`

Comment: @Zarko The two subfigures are placed one above the other (note width of environment and paragraph break between them), so no need for the widths to add up to `\linewidth`. **Ahmed**: What if you use `width=0.8\linewidth` instead of `scale=0.2`? (Though I wouldn't think it mattered..)

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I cant remember why i assume, that the figure are placed side by side ... only with this assumption my answer has a sense. Now after OP edit of his question I see, that he like that the first i also rotated ... so the height of the first image seems to be `0.8\textwidth`. I will delete my comment and maybe provide on answer :-)

Comment: @Zarko No, his problem is that the image is rotated when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Ahmed: could your problem be of the same nature as [Why are high resolution portrait orientation images rotated automatically?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/751695)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is after editing little bit more clear, however the MWE, which would show, what you looking for, is still missing. Si I anticipate, that you probably like to obtain something like this:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{lipsum}   
\usepackage{subcaption}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}[!h]{0.9\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[height=\linewidth,angle=270]{example-image-a}
    \end{center}
    \caption{cap1}
    \label{fig1}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[!h]{0.9\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{center}
    \caption{cap2}
    \label{fig2}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{cap}
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
    \end{document}
```

Rotation is defined manually, if you like to do this automatically, you need first to measure size image (see @TorbjørnT. comment).